# Opening a gif full screen in a Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, gif, display

I have a batch script and I need it to open a gif file and display full screen.
I have done research and all I can find is how to open the gif, but not resize it correctly.
The code I find wants to save it as a 500x500 for example, but not display it.

The path is c:\temp\move.gif

I have the above line in the code so it just opens the gif.....

I have tried using

```
START /MAX "" "C:\Windows\System32\CMD.exe
pause
```

But it didnt work either

Comment: Read the documentation of the program you use to open the GIF image. Batch don't know how to handle these files, it's a third-party application that do it - even if natively shipped with Windows. You didn't specified it, neither provided the current batch file you're writing. We can't guess.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Microsoft Photos app for Windows 10 is a universal app and does not support command line options. You can start it with `start ms-photos:` but it will not open to a file. Which program are you trying to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com/). Here are [some examples](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-useful-commandline-irfanview-tools-working-images/) of command line usage.  To simply open something full screen, you should be able to do this:

```
i_view32.exe c:\temp\move.gif /fs
```

All command line parameters can be [found here](https://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/IrfanView_Command_Line_Options).